# How to convert JSON from KAFKA to pass it to Spark's machine learning Algorithm

Tags: java, json, apache-spark, apache-kafka, apache-spark-mllib

I am trying to learn spark and spark-streaming using Java. And developing an IOT application.
I am having a KAFKA server in place which accepts JSON data and I am able to parse it using SQLContext and foreach function.

Data format is as follows,

```
[{"t":1481368346000,"sensors":[{"s":"s1","d":"+149.625"},{"s":"s2","d":"+23.062"},{"s":"s3","d":"+16.375"},{"s":"s4","d":"+235.937"},{"s":"s5","d":"+271.437"},{"s":"s6","d":"+265.937"},{"s":"s7","d":"+295.562"},{"s":"s8","d":"+301.687"}]}]
```

In this t is a timestamp of each data stream 
and sensors is array of sensor data with s as a name of each sensor and d containing a data.

What I have done till now is,

```
    JavaPairInputDStream<String, String> directKafkaStream = 
            KafkaUtils.createDirectStream(ssc,
                                          String.class,
                                          String.class, 
                                          StringDecoder.class,
                                          StringDecoder.class,
                                          kafkaParams, 
                                          topics);

    SQLContext sqlContext = spark.sqlContext();
    StreamingLinearRegressionWithSGD model = new StreamingLinearRegressionWithSGD().setInitialWeights(Vectors.zeros(2));

    JavaDStream<String> json = directKafkaStream.map(new Function<Tuple2<String,String>, String>() {
        public String call(Tuple2<String,String> message) throws Exception {
            return message._2();
        };
    });
    json.print();

    json.foreachRDD(new VoidFunction<JavaRDD<String>>() {
        @Override
        public void call(JavaRDD<String> jsonRecord) throws Exception {
            System.out.println("JSON Record ---- "+jsonRecord);
             if(!jsonRecord.isEmpty()){
                    Dataset<Row> timestamp = sqlContext.read().json(jsonRecord).select("t");
                    timestamp.printSchema();
                    timestamp.show(false);

                    Dataset<Row> data = sqlContext.read().json(jsonRecord).select("sensors");
                    data.printSchema();
                    data.show(false);
                    //DF in table
                    Dataset<Row> df = data.select(org.apache.spark.sql.functions.explode(org.apache.spark.sql.functions.col("sensors")))
                            .toDF("sensors").select("sensors.s","sensors.d").where("sensors.s = 's1'");
                    Row firstRow = df.head();

                    String valueOfFirstSensor = firstRow.getString(1);
                    System.out.println("---------valueOfFirstSensor --------"+ valueOfFirstSensor);
                    double[] values = new double[1];
                    values[0] = firstRow.getDouble(0);
                    new LabeledPoint(timestamp.head().getDouble(0), Vectors.dense(values));

                    df.show(false);
                }
        }
    });

    ssc.start();
    ssc.awaitTermination();
```

What I want to do is, convert json which is JavaDStream into a data structure which **StreamingLinearRegressionWithSGD model** accepts.

When I try to use sparks's map function to map json stream to JavaDStream as follows,

```
        JavaDStream<LabeledPoint> forML =  json.map(new Function<String, LabeledPoint>() {

            @Override
            public LabeledPoint call(String jsonRecord) throws Exception {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                System.out.println("\n\n\n here is JSON in"+ jsonRecord);

                LabeledPoint returnObj = null;
                 if(!jsonRecord.isEmpty()){
                        Dataset<Row> timestamp = sqlContext.read().json(jsonRecord).select("t");
                        timestamp.printSchema();
                        timestamp.show(false);

                        Dataset<Row> data = sqlContext.read().json(jsonRecord).select("sensors");
                        data.printSchema();
                        data.show(false);
                        //DF in table
                        Dataset<Row> df = data.select(org.apache.spark.sql.functions.explode(org.apache.spark.sql.functions.col("sensors")))
                                .toDF("sensors").select("sensors.s","sensors.d").where("sensors.s = 's1'");
                        Row firstRow = df.head();

                        String valueOfFirstSensor = firstRow.getString(1);
                        System.out.println("---------valueOfFirstSensor --------"+ valueOfFirstSensor);
                        double[] values = new double[1];
                        values[0] = firstRow.getDouble(0);
                        returnObj = new LabeledPoint(timestamp.head().getDouble(0), Vectors.dense(values));
                        df.show(false);
                    }
                 return returnObj;

            }
        }).cache();


model.trainOn(forML);
```

And call model.trainOn it fails with NullPointerException at

```
Dataset<Row> timestamp = sqlContext.read().json(jsonRecord).select("t");
```

Now the questions I am having are,

1. Am I doing this right?
2. How I will be able to predict values and why and how I need to create a different stream to pass it on to predictOn function of model?
3. I will be receiving multiple sensors but single value for each sensor, and there can be thousands of such streams, how I can create different model for each of those thousand sensors and predict for such a vast amount of data efficiently?
4. Are there any other good machine learning algorithms or approaches which can be utilized for this type of sensor data?